# Image of a circle by a linear, complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

$\def\C{\mathbf C}$Unfortunately, I do not understand the approach required to solve the following problem.
Let $ S = {z \in \C : |z- (1+2i)| = 1 }$ and let $f: \C \rightarrow \C $ a linear function given by $ f(z) = (2+3i)z +4+5i$. Determine the set $f[S]$, ie the image of the circle by $f$.

I understand that I am supposed to input set $S$ into $f $ to find out its image by $f$. I have therefore attempted to isolate $z$ in $S$ and to substitute it into $f(z)$. This was unsuccessful. The solution uses the fact that I can let $w= f(z)$ and then let $z = f^{-1}(w)$ which is then substituted into $S$ to generate a set of the form $|w-w_0| = R$, ie another circle. This substitution is confusing me, as I cannot see why a set in terms of $w$ is an image of $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the definition of the image set: 
$$ f[S] := \{f(s) \mid s \in S\}, $$
that is 
$$ w \in f[S] \iff \exists s \in S: f(s) = w $$
Now, as $f$ is invertible, as any non-constant affine map is, we have $f(s) = w$ iff $s = f^{-1}(w)$, that is 
$$ w \in f[S] \iff \exists s \in S: f^{-1}(w) = s \iff f^{-1}(w) \in S $$